# how to update table in silex (PHP micro-framework)?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, slice

I have used $sql to insert data into table using below code in model

```
        $sql = "INSERT into $database"; 

        $sql .= ( ;           
        foreach($data as $key => $value)
        {
            $sql .= "$key, ";
        }           
        $sql = substr($sql, 0);


        $sql .= ) VALUES ( ;
        foreach($data as $key => $value)
        {
            $sql .= "'$value', ";
        }
        $sql = substr($sql, 0);

        $sql .=);
```

my problem is how to update sametable using silex

Answer (score 0):

according to [silex documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/providers/doctrine.html) you should use doctrine ORM provider:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    'db.options' => array(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        'driver'   => 'pdo_sqlite',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        'path'     => __DIR__.'/app.db',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    ),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
));                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

$app['db']->insert('tablename', array(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    'key1' => 'val1',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    'key2' => 'val2',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    'key3' => 'val3'));
```